# REGEX in stored procedure in "="/like clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, inner-join

I've created a stored procedure with 3 inner joins (please, don't judge me :D):

```
SELECT 
    T.Name, A.Value 
FROM
    Table AS T
INNER JOIN
    TableAnotherTable AS TA ON TA.ID_1 = T.ID_1
INNER JOIN
    AnotherTable AS A ON A.ID_2 = TA.ID_2
INNER JOIN
    EndTable AS ET ON ET.Value = A.Value
```

`TableAnotherTable` is the association table between `Table` and `AnotherTable`. So, this stored procedure works in some cases (if `ET.Value` is **equal** to `A.Value`).

But if:

```
ET.Value = 'SOME\THING\RIGHT\<ABC>\THERE'
A.Value= 'SOME\THING\RIGHT\{DEFGHILM}\THERE'
```

the stored procedure must also work.

How can I change the last `ON` of the inner join clause (with "=") to something like:

```
Regex("pattern1", E.Value) like Regex("pattern", A.Value)
```

where `pattern` and `pattern1` are `({.*?})` or `(<.*?>)`?

Thanks

Examples:

```
ET.Value = 'HI'
A.Value = 'HI'
true

ET.Value = 'SOME\THING\RIGHT\<ABC>\THERE'
A.Value = 'SOME\THING\RIGHT\{DEFGHILMNOP}\THERE'
true

ET.Value = 'HOME\SWEET\HOME\<12345>\'
A.Value = 'HOME\SWEET\HOME\{4875928346}\'
true

ET.Value = 'EXAMPLE\<1234>'
A.Value = 'EG\{1234}'
false

ET.Value = 'dog'
A.Value = 'cat'
false
```

Comment: The text bewteen <> and {} must be equal too ? the only changed is the encapsulation ?

Comment: No, the text is different. The part that interests me is the one outside the <> and {}

Comment: So bascally you want to ignore everything between `<>` or `{}`?

Comment: Further questions: Do you need to match up to the third backslash and after the last backslash or is it really just `SameValue1DIFFERENTSameValue2` where the SameValues can be anything(and just match)?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica for example:
SOMETHING\<1>\SOMETHING match SOMETHING\{2}\SOMETHING -> true
SOMETHING\BLABLA\<1>\BLA match SOMETHING\BLABLA\{2}\BLA -> true
some\<1>\thing\bla match something\{2}\blabla -> false

Comment: @SalmanA exactly

Comment: @rlnnclt Can you add some examples (and expected results) like these to the question please? Perhaps even with real values other than <1> so we're able to derive which value can be different.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica Sure, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no regexp replace function in SQL Server. The closest you can get is by using `PATINDEX` to locate the `<{` and `}>' characters and` STUFF` everything in between:

```sql
SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN val1_new = val2_new THEN 'match' END
FROM (VALUES
    ('SOMETHING\<1>\SOMETHING',  'SOMETHING\{2}\SOMETHING'),
    ('SOMETHING\BLABLA\<1>\BLA', 'SOMETHING\BLABLA\{2}\BLA'),
    ('SOME\<1>\THING\BLA',       'SOMETHING\{2}\BLABLA'),
    ('dog',                      'dog')
) AS t(val1, val2)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        PATINDEX('%[<{]%', val1) AS val1_pos1,
        PATINDEX('%[>}]%', val1) AS val1_pos2,
        PATINDEX('%[<{]%', val2) AS val2_pos1,
        PATINDEX('%[>}]%', val2) AS val2_pos2
) AS ca1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN val1_pos1 > 0 AND val1_pos2 > 0 THEN STUFF(val1, val1_pos1, val1_pos2 - val1_pos1 + 1, '') ELSE val1 END,
        CASE WHEN val2_pos1 > 0 AND val2_pos2 > 0 THEN STUFF(val2, val2_pos1, val2_pos2 - val2_pos1 + 1, '') ELSE val2 END
) AS ca3(val1_new, val2_new)
```

Comment: And how can I include this case:
ET.Value = 'HI' e A.Value = 'Hi' -> match 
?

Comment: If both characters are not found then you compare them as-is.

Comment: In which way? I'm sorry but I'm new on Stored Procedures (yes, I know I've started with a complex problem)

Comment: I've tried with `SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN val1_new = val2_new OR val1 = val2 THEN 'match' END` and it works. [Result of test](https://ibb.co/GpcDG4J)

Comment: I have actually edited it so that it checks if the delimiters are present and does not fail if they are missing. But again, I'd rather write a function that removes everything between two delimiters. The query will otherwise have too much noise.

Comment: thanks so much, but now I must integrate this solution in my stored procedure:

`SELECT 
    T.Name, A.Value 
FROM
    Table AS T
INNER JOIN
    TableAnotherTable AS TA ON TA.ID_1 = T.ID_1
INNER JOIN
    AnotherTable AS A ON A.ID_2 = TA.ID_2
INNER JOIN
    EndTable AS ET ON YOURSOLUTION, maybe`

Comment: Change `INNER JOIN EndTable` to `CROSS JOIN EndTable` (no ON clause), then add the CROSS APPLY from my answer... val1 would be A.Value and val2 would be ET.Value. Finally add `WHERE val1_new = val2_new` at the end.

Comment: You are my life saver. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the text without the part between <> and {} :

Here the join condition :

```
LEFT(ET.VALUE,CHARINDEX('<', ET.VALUE)-1) +  RIGHT(ET.VALUE,LEN(ET.VALUE)- CHARINDEX('>', ET.VALUE))
=
LEFT(A.Value,CHARINDEX('{', A.Value)-1) +  RIGHT(A.Value,LEN(A.Value)- CHARINDEX('}', A.Value))
```

But it can be bad in terms of performance because you tranform the key used to join the table.

Comment: This doesn't work because if I have something like: ET.Value = 'HI' e A.Value = 'Hi', there aren't {} or <>.

Comment: @rlnnclt Then just add `ON (ET.VALUE = A.VALUE OR LEFT ...)`

Comment: You need `NULLIF(CHARINDEX..., 0)` just in case you can;t find the value